# How to optimize client-server connection

Tags: java, client-server, multiplayer

I am writing multiplayer shooter on java from scratch. I've already written client, server and game classes.
General description:
Every client has local copy of game. Client sends requests on server on every user's input, and also listens to updates from server in a while cycle.
When server receives request, it updates game's state, and then sends current game's state to every client. Server handles all requests in parallel.
I use UDP connection.

Everything works well, when I have only one user on server, I can't spot any delays. But when another user joins server, game start lagging so much, even if I don't move 2nd user.

Are there any advices, how can I optimize my game and get rid of these lags?

I am expecting to receive some ideas how can I optimize my game.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is fairly broad, and impossible to answer without you sharing the code. You may want to check [ask].